# Search String from database of text files, Ignoring special characters and punctuation

Tags: string, algorithm, search

I recently came across this interview question which involves searching of a string from a collection of text files.

How would you search a database for a matching string ignoring certain punctuation/special characters? What pre-processing would you do?

I understand string searching is pretty common problem. I want to get insight on how to ignore special characters or punctuation from a string can be ignored while searching it inside the text.

Solutions I tried/attempted-:

Pattern matching algorithms like KMP or BM which takes O(n) time to compare string with each word inside the text files. I am not sure if using any of those is valid approach.

I also thought about processing all the text files inside the database into a Trie kind of structure then search through the Trie. Potential issue with that can happen when we have millions of text files inside the database to search and I'll end up creating Trie for that.

I am not sure if hash table can be useful in this case??

I am more interested towards the approach of this problem then code.

Comment: The question was about "pre-processing".  So the task was to remove punctuation and special characters.  Punctuation always occurs at the end so you don't want to remove periods (abbreviations) in the middle of a string.  I assume the string was stored intact in the database. So to ignore special characters so I would remove the special character.  Then I would perform the search by words and look for best match.  So my preprocessing would be to break the string into words and remove all special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first , we will remove the special characters from the text file, here is simple code how to do it

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main () {
char str[256];

cout << "Enter the name of an existing text file: ";
cin.get (str,256);    

std::ifstream is(str);     // open file
string s ="";
char c;
while (is.get(c)) {// loop getting single characters
if((c >= 97 && c<= 122)|| c==' ' ||(c >=65 && c<=90))
    s+=c;
}

is.close();                // close file

return 0;
}
```

now we have text with no special characters in `string 's'` , now u can apply `KMP` algorithm

Comment: Ok, that make sense. Is there a way or a vriation of KMP or some other pattern searching algo which allow us to ignore special chacters. Also Do you think "Trie" approach can be used here instead.